# Copying values from one DataGridView to another

Tags: c#, database, forms, ms-access, datagridview

I am developing a C# application and one of the components consists of a form with 2 DataGridView objects. I would like to trigger an event in the double click event handler of the data grid view that will copy two values from the left DGV to the right DGV. The left one consists of only 2 fields and the right one has 4 fields. I am struggling with the copying process. This Drawing will explain the situation.(I'm using a MS - Access Database)

[image]

What would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: What should the values for "Attendance" and "Excuse" be in the destination table?

Comment: That's just it, the copy process is just to set the member name and number an the right side DGV, the user should enter the remaining fields runtime

Comment: Right, but before the user updates them, what value should these fields take? Should it be NULL, assuming the Access table allows this?

Comment: I would update both in the same event if the parameters are the same. If they are in two separate dbs then just make two ADO calls to each and update them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a Data Source you can't edit the DGV items directly. You have to add the new row to the "Session" table in the database. The DGV should then update itself to reflect the new data in the table (or maybe you have to call Refresh() on it).

edit: try something like this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Member a = (Member) dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        Session b;
        //do something to create b from a
        tableSessions.Add(b);                      
    }
```

Comment: i had an idea that is what the solution would entail, but now the question still remains : i can enter values in the right side DGV and simply use the Update method of the data adapter to set the values in my ms-access table, but i still would like to know how to copy values from one DGV to another, to save time entering values on the right side DGV

Comment: Let me make a correction: you can *edit* the values in the DGV directly, you just can't add rows directly.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do though, are you trying to add a row from the left DGV to the right, or modify one of the the rows on the right?

Comment: Here is what i would like to do : I only need one DGV, namely sessions, where the user builds up n session. In such a session there are multiple entries, each containing 4 fields. What i want is to spare time and have the abillity to select from a list of members(left DGV) to help the user get initial values in each new entry he makes. Example i double click on the left side DGV row with an name and member number and it copies it to the right side DGV, now the user only has 2 more fields to enter instead of 4.